# Integrating with respect to time

Tags: integration

I'm trying to compute U from $\dot{U} = 1 ft/s^2$ with respect to time. I feel it's a simple concept I just forgot. Yet I can't find any good material to explain it. I need to integrate with respect to t get velocity from acceleration

I know

$$U = \int\dot{U}dt $$

so I set up

$$U = \int 1dt $$

if doing that

$$ U = 1t + C $$

Comment: The units of $ft/s^2$ don't represent velocity. These are the units for accelleration

Comment: $\dot{U}$ has units of acceleration. So you need to integrate twice to get position

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I meant acceleration to velocity. Just finished a 12 hour work day.

Comment: In that case you are correct. Are you given any initial values, so that you can find the constant $c$?

Comment: I was not. But it just seems off. Because while it's in response to time, it's for the given instant. So C doesn't seem like it should be there.

Comment: You would also need some time conditions - usually an initial condition to figure out the constant. With the information you have given us so far, the method and calculation is correct